Axis and Angle of rotation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}-i&-1\\1&i\end{bmatrix}$
I have made use of the following formulas,
\begin{align}
\theta&=2\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{e^{-i\alpha}Tr(X)}{2}\bigg)\\
n_i&=\frac{e^{-i\alpha}Tr(X\sigma_x)}{2\sin\theta/2}\\
e^{i\alpha}&=\sqrt{\det(X)}
\end{align}
Please check Can I find the axis of rotation for any single-qubit gate? for the reference.
$$
X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}-i&-1\\1&i\end{bmatrix}\\
e^{i\alpha}=\sqrt{\det(X)}=1\\
\theta=2\cos^{-1}(\frac{1.0}{2})=2\cos^{-1}(0)=2\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi\\
Tr(X\sigma_x)=0\implies n_1=0\\
X\sigma_y=X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}-i&-1\\1&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}-i&-1\\-1&-i\end{bmatrix}\\
\implies Tr(X\sigma_y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.-2i=-\sqrt{2}i\implies n_2=\frac{i.1.-\sqrt{2}i}{2.1}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\sqrt{2}\\
Tr(X\sigma_z)=0\implies n_3=0
$$
Why am I not getting a unit vector here ?

Maybe you want to double-check your calculation for $n_i$? You skipped many steps.

@Yunzhe I tried to add little more steps to it. Could you please look into it ?

Do the calculation carefully. Your gate is Hadamard-like and its axis won't be the Pauli axis.

@Yunzhe Okay thanks. I got it, it seems to be rather $(0,1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ which should be correct as it is a unit vector, turned out I was looking at different place for errors before.

@Yunzhe I noticed people tend to not be careful there - they often say a "$\pi/2$" gate is a Hadamard gate (because both send $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ to the equator of the Bloch sphere) but indeed the Hadamard is a rotation about some diagonal axis
